# Give an O(n+m) algorithm that returns a node for which if we delete we get a maximum number of components

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have this homework :

Give an O(n+m) algorithm that returns a node of an undirected graph for which if we remove it, the remaining graph will consistent of the maximum number of components.

My idea:
First, i thought if we delete the node with max degree we get the result. But since it says O(n+m) i thought maybe i should use DFS. I read that DFS can help to look for bridges, but it doesn't give back a node but an edge instead. So my question, can i use DFS and look for bridges and for all vertices with bridge i use the one with max degree and that's the answer.

Is it correct? Or looking for vertices with bridges is a bad idea? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Max degree doesn't work, you can think of a wheel graph (a single hub vertex connected to every vertex in a cycle) and connect a single isolated vertex to the rim of the wheel. If you remove the hub, which has max degree) you get 1 component, but removing the connected one on the rim isolates the added vertex and gives 2.

Comment: $n=|V|$, $m=|E|$?

Comment: Yes n=|V| and m=|E|

Comment: Are you familiar with the linear-time algorithm for finding articulation vertices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On GeeksForGeeks has a simple explanation for your question, for computing the articulation points.
[GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/?ref=lbp).